# Why is execstack required to execute code on the heap?

Tags: c, gcc

I wrote the code below to test shellcode (for unlinking `/tmp/passwd`) for an assignment in a security class.

When I compile with `gcc -o test -g test.c`, I get a segfault on the jump into the shellcode.

When I postprocess the binary with `execstack -s test`, I no longer get a segfault and the shellcode executes correctly, removing `/tmp/passwd`.

I am running `gcc 4.7.2`. It seems like it is bad idea to require the stack to be executable in order to make the heap executable, since there are many more legitimate use cases of the latter than the former.

**Is this expected behavior? If so, what is the rationale?**

```
#include <stdio.h>                                     
#include <stdlib.h>                                    


char* shellcode;                                       


int main(){                                            
    shellcode = malloc(67);                            
    FILE* code = fopen("shellcode.bin", "rb");      
    fread(shellcode, 1, 67, code);                     

    int (*fp)(void) = (int (*) (void)) shellcode;      
    fp();                                              
}
```

Here is the output of `xxd shellcode.bin`:

```
0000000: eb28 5e89 760c 31c0 8846 0bfe c0fe c0fe  .(^.v.1..F......           
0000010: c0fe c0fe c0fe c0fe c0fe c0fe c0fe c089  ................           
0000020: f3cd 8031 db89 d840 cd80 e8d3 ffff ff2f  ...1...@......./           
0000030: 746d 702f 7061 7373 7764                 tmp/passwd
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-execute_bit

Comment: @HansPassant, NX seems to be useable at the granularity of a Page Table Entry. The technology is somewhat orthogonal to my question, which is about the rationale of combining stack and heap protections into one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real "unexpected" behavior is that setting the flag makes the *heap* executable as well as the stack.  The flag is intended for use with executables that generate stack-based thunks (such as gcc when you take the address of a nested function) and shouldn't really affect the heap.  But Linux implements this by globally making ALL readable pages executable.

If you want finer-grained control, you could instead use the `mprotect` system call to control executable permissions on a per-page basis -- Add code like:

```
uintptr_t pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
#define PAGE_START(P) ((uintptr_t)(P) & ~(pagesize-1))
#define PAGE_END(P)   (((uintptr_t)(P) + pagesize - 1) & ~(pagesize-1))
mprotect((void *)PAGE_START(shellcode), PAGE_END(shellcode+67) - PAGE_START(shellcode),
         PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC);
```

Comment: [Unexpected exec permission from mmap when assembly files included in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58260465) has some more detail about the "read implies exec" kernel feature that `-zexecstack` uses.

Comment: Update: with modern kernels, `-zexecstack` now truly only does what the name says, it no longer sets READ_IMPLIES_EXEC: [Linux default behavior against \`.data\` section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64833715)

Answer (score 5):

> Is this expected behavior?

Looking at the Linux kernel code, I think that the kernel-internal name for this flag is "read implies exec". So yes, I think that it's expected.

> It seems like it is bad idea to require the stack to be executable in order to make the heap executable, since there are many more legitimate use cases of the latter than the former.

Why would you need the complete heap to be executable? If you really need to dynamically generate machine code and run it or so, you can explicitly allocate executable memory using the [`mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) syscall.

> what is the rationale?

I think that the idea is that this flag can be used for legacy programs that expect that everything that's readable is also executable. Those programs might try to run stuff on the stack and they might try to run stuff on the heap, so it's all permitted.