# Hello World in ARM Assembly without data section

Tags: c, assembly, arm, shellcode

I have a "Hello, World!" program in ARM assembly language and I want to convert it into shell code to execute it in a memory region. In Intel Assembly language I got rid of the .data section since only the .text section is being used when converting to shell code. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593214/linux-shellcode-hello-world))

Now I am struggling to do the same in ARMs assembly language. The basis is the following code:

**ARM Assembly Hello World**

```
.global _start

_start:
    mov r7, #4
    mov r0, #1
    ldr r1,=string
    mov r2, #12
    swi 0
    mov r7, #1
    swi 0

.data
string:
  .ascii "Hello, World"
```

**Modified ARM Assembly Hello World to omit the .data section**

```
.global _start
.global mymessage

mymessage:
    mov r7, #4
    mov r0, #1
    pop {r1}
    mov r2, #12
    swi 0
    mov r7, #1
    swi 0

_start:
    bl mymessage
    .ascii "Hello, World"
```

But this doesn't work, since this is an "*illegal instruction*" apparently. Any ideas?

Comment: ARM already has PC-relative addressing, and in any case, `bl` does not push the return address on the stack.

Comment: `bl` is the equivalent, but ARM does not put the return address on the stack. But since ARM has PC relative addressing you don't need the trick at all.

Comment: Ah, I understand, thanks!

Comment: since you string is a constant read-only in either case it could be in .text doesnt have to be in .data

Comment: Here is a nice setup to test this out: https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/tree/e3477c16c8d5a59e239a202760223f4d86e199c9/linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARM already has PC-relative addressing, and in any case, `bl` does not push the return address on the stack.

This works:

```
.global _start

_start:
    mov r7, #4
    mov r0, #1
    adr r1, string
    mov r2, #12
    swi 0
    mov r7, #1
    swi 0

string:
  .ascii "Hello, World"
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, this works! Now we just need to figure out how to convert this into shellcode. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you want to convert ... just run it through the assembler and you get the bytes.

Comment: We want to extract the shellcode like x04\xe7\x06...., and the bytes of the "string .ascii" area are separated from the rest of the bytes. Do I just put them all into a "combined" shellcode to execute it?

Comment: Yes. Not sure what you mean by "separated" they should come directly after the code.

Comment: Never mind, I got it ;) Thanks for your help, @Jester!

Comment: @Marvin - where you are to get the actual shellcode to work in a separate program?

Comment: @InfinitelyManic What do you mean exactly? Are you asking how I am executing the shellcode in another program?

Comment: @Marvin, I mean did you copy the Assembly byte code into a C program and successfully execute it?