# Running data shellcode in c executable

Tags: assembly, memory-management, x86, reverse-engineering

I am working on this c program. I am compiling it with gcc on a 64 bits x64 linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char buffer[]={0x90,0x90,0xC3};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void (*fct)();
    fct=buffer;
    fct();
    return 0;
}
```

0x90 opcode is NOP

0xC3 opcode is RET

I want to know what i should do in order to run this program. I get a segfault when running it...

Thanks

Comment: The `.data` section is probably not executable.  Use `const char buffer` to put it in the `.rodata` section, which is (because it's linked as part of the text segment).

Comment: thanks but it does not work

Comment: `const char buffer[] = {...};` works for me with or without optimization: https://godbolt.org/z/0lMuL9.  I ran it on my desktop and it exited without faulting.  What did you do differently that made it not work?

Comment: Update: more recent `ld` versions put `.rodata` in non-executable pages, presumably to reduce exposure of data as ROP / Spectre gadgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Compile with `-z execstack` to enable Linux's read-implies-exec feature for your executable.  Despite the name, it applies to *all* pages, not just the stack.

---

The program is faulting because the `buffer` symbol goes into the `.data` section that in turns goes, along with other sections, into an ELF segment mapped Read-write but **not executable**.

To make the `buffer` executable the best course of action would be to make a new ELF segment with flags RWE and assign it a new section, then tell GCC to put `buffer` in this new section.
This could be done, *in principle* with the following linker script:

```
PHDRS
{
        MYSEG PT_LOAD FLAGS (7);
}
SECTIONS
{
        MYSECT : { *(MYSECT) } : MYSEG
}
```

, changing the source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char buffer[] __attribute__ ((section ("MYSECT"))) ={0x90,0x90,0xC3};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void (*fct)();
    fct=buffer;
    fct();
    return 0;
}
```

and the compiling passing the `-T` switch to GCC.

But this **won't** work.
GCC uses a default linker script based on the command line and the `-T` switch replace it entirely.
It's possible to get the script used by GCC with `-Wl,-verbose` and update it.

If we split the compilation and the linking by first invoking GCC with `-c` and then LD, we'd get only one segment because that's what we put in the linker script - thereby defeating all our efforts to make *only* `buffer` the only executable data.

---

With `-z execstack` we actually only tell GCC to use a linker script that sets the `GNU_STACK` ELF segment RWE.
This is a marker segment (size and lma are zero) used by the loader to setup the correct permissions for the stack pages.
[But in truth it is used as a compatibility switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276488/why-is-execstack-required-to-execute-code-on-the-heap) - when the stack is set as executable the loader will set *all* the writable pages as executable.

If you are playing with shellcodes `-z execstack` will make it easy, however it exposes your application to a boatload of attacks, but I guess this is what you needed in the first place.

Comment: More about `-zexecstack` and the Linux `READ_IMPLIES_EXEC` "execution domain" it enables:  [Unexpected exec permission from mmap when assembly files included in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58260465)